# before point 3 numbers should accept 0-9 after point decimal 4 digits should accept

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to validate the text box server side by using regular exp which should accept at most 3 digits [0-9] before the decimal point and 4 digits [0-9] after the decimal point. The part after the decimal point should be restricted to exactly 4 digits (not more or less)

Correct examples:

32.4240
10.0240
100.6400
2.0260
43.0000

Comment: I think you should have a look on [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of regex.

Comment: For **which** language? Why javascript, java, c#, asp.net **and** c?

Comment: So what happens when someone enters 1.00005? Should it be rounded, truncated, rejected?

Comment: Should it accept numbers without fractional part? like 357? Or with less than 4 digits after point? Like 257.03 ? You should read regexp tutorial, regexp are pretty simple for such tasks

Comment: HI Elliott Frisch  , in c#

Comment: @HI Vesan  : it should reject and it should popup a error msg

Comment: @HI user1940679  : it should accept only 4 digits value  not less than 4 digits.  like  32.4240 10.0240 100.6400 2.0260 43.0000

Answer (score 1):

The ["#" custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD) serves as a digit-placeholder symbol. If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in the result string.

```
value.ToString("###.####");
```

Comment: Good answer, but OP tagged the question with several tags referencing different languages. We don't really know if he wants JavaScript, Java, C, or your answer, C#.

Comment: @LucasBaizer You forgot asp.net

Comment: Yes you are correct @LucasBaizer. But I have answer for the one which I think will help. :D Correct Elliott. :D

Comment: This is useful for formatting a number, but OP says "I need to validate the text box...", so the question is probably about parsing the number from a string rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regexp then try ^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,4})$

Comment: thanq i solved problem 90 percent  but when we give value like 12.0000 it not taking and not displaying any error

Comment: sorry i got it ..Thanq so much

Comment: if we put 0 it is showing error user can also put 0

Comment: How do you using this regexp? It should match 0. Maybe you are testing value just like if(value) and 0 is false in many programming languages. You should check length of value if you want check if it entered by user